# How to add a constraint to an existing model via cplex .net API?

Tags: c#, cplex

In the API, mostly you first add the constraints via AddRange, and than the columns/variables via NumVar. Then call solve. after that, how to add an additional constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created the problem as an ***IloCplex*** object, you can use the **problem modification routines.**

You can any of a number of ILOG routines to modify the constraints, variables or the right-hand side. (This is standard practice while performing **Sensitivity Analysis** after obtaining an LP's solution.

**[This page](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~gendron/IFT6551/CPLEX/HTML/overviewcplex/modify.html)** has good list of the modification routines. (Look at the Java column in the table for .NET routines.)

Per the documentation the following changes can be made:

- - adding rows and columns to the constraint matrix,

    - deleting rows and columns from the constraint matrix,
    - changing the sense of the objective function,
    - changing the value of coefficients in the constraint matrix,
    - changing an objective or right-hand side coefficient,
    - changing the bounds on a variable,
    - changing the sense of a constraint, and
    - changing names of rows or columns.